# If variable true change <option> to disabled

Tags: php, variables, html-select, disabled-input

Hi i wanna show `<option value"Glock-18">` only if variable `$money > 99`.. how can i do this? I try this but this is not work..

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="gun">
<option value="" selected disabled>Pistol</option>
    <?php if($money > 99){
        echo "<option value="Glock-18">Glock-18 100$</option>";
    }
        elseif ($money < 100) {
        echo "<option disabled value="Glock-18">Glock-18 100$</option>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: You don't need `elseif ($money < 100)` because the previous if already defines that condition. Just use `else`

Comment: He will need it indeed cause if the $money == 99,5, it will cause a problem to him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the shorthand like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="gun">
<option value="" selected disabled>Pistol</option>
<option value='Glock - 18' <?= $money<100 ? 'disabled' : ''?>>Glock-18 100$</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="gun">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Pistol</option>
        <?php 
          if($money > 99) {
              echo "<option value='Glock-18'>Glock-18 100$</option>";
          } elseif ($money < 100) {
              echo "<option disabled value='Glock-18'>Glock-18 100$</option>";
          }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, 
The problem of your code is that you have used double quotes inside a double quote. I have replaced the main double quote with a single quote in below code.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="gun">
<option value="" selected disabled>Pistol</option>
    <?php if($money > 99){
        echo '<option value="Glock-18">Glock-18 100$</option>';
    }
        elseif ($money < 100) {
        echo '<option disabled value="Glock-18">Glock-18 100$</option>';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="gun">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Pistol</option>
        <?php if($money > 99){
           $disabled ="";
        }else{
           $disabled ="disabled";
        }?>
    <option <?php echo $disabled; ?> value="Glock-18">Glock-18 100$</option>
    </select>
</form>
```